# Priority-based queuing in queue block does not work

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to use priority based queuing in my queue block. My process is as follows:

[source, wait, queue, packing_machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2mXZ.png)

On exit of the wait block, the agent gets assigned a priority in agent.atrPriority. In queue I have selected Queuing: Priority based and at Agent priority I use: agent.atrPriority.
By printing to the console I am checking if the sequence in which the agents enter the packing_machine block is correct (according to their priority), but it isn't. It keeps sending the agents from queue to packing_station on a FIFO basis.

I have tried assiging agent.atrPriority at different places in the model, but I do not think that that is the problem. i have also tried using agents comparison with agent1.atrPriority.before(agent2.atrPriority); but it gives the error ' Cannot invoke before(int) on the primitive type int.

Does anyone know why it is not working accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queue is working, so it is not a bug.

Try a quick test: put another delay between the Wait and the Queue. Set the delay duration to be 0.0001 sec or something tiny.

If this fixes it, the culprit is that you change the `atrPriority` field "on Exit" of Wait, which is effectively too late. It basically changes after the downstream Queue accesses the priority value.

Another option: change the `atrPriority` value before you call `wait.free(...)`. This way, you can be sure the priority is set to the right value before the agent enters the queue